# How do i get the array to hold the number of games played and run it for each player?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have an assignment where two users are to enter their names, then get the number of games they played, then get the scores for each game that they played, put the scores in an array (or two arrays???), then compare the two arrays and scores to see who won each game or if they're tied, then display results. I don't have to sort it or search through it I don't believe.

Ss my teacher says getting the scores has to be a void method, but I'm not sure how I get the values from this void method into arrays for each player so I can compare the score values.

```
    public class Lab9 {
public static void inputScores(int[] array, String name)  {
    String inputScores = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        inputScores = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(name + " enter your score for game " + i);
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputScores);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numberOfGames = getPositiveIntOrQuit("How many games were played?",  "Lab 9 (by Jarvis),");



       String  name = getStringOrQuit("Player 1-What is your name?", "Lab 9 (by Jarvis");

       String name1 = getStringOrQuit(" Player 2 - What is your name?","Lab 9(by Jarvis");


        int score = getNonNegativeIntOrQuit(name  +  "  enter your score for game" ,  "Lab 9 (by Jarvis)");



        }

        public static String getStringOrQuit(String prompt, String title) {
            String userInputString;

                userInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt, title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                // Did user hit Cancel or OK with nothing typed?
                if (userInputString == null || userInputString.trim().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No input, so program will terminate now.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            return userInputString;
        }  // getStringOrQuit



        public static int getPositiveIntOrQuit(String prompt, String title) {
            String userInputString;
            int userInputInt = 0;

            do {
                userInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt, title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                // Did user hit Cancel or OK with nothing typed?
                if (userInputString == null || userInputString.trim().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No input, so program will terminate now.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else
                try {
                    userInputInt = Integer.parseInt(userInputString);    // This line might throw an exception.
                    // Ok, if conversion in above line worked, check if input is a positive integer.
                    if (userInputInt < 1)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bad input value. It must be a positive integer.",
                                "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bad input value. It must be a positive integer.",
                                        "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

            } while (userInputInt < 1);

            return userInputInt;
        }  // getPositiveIntOrQuit



        public static int getNonNegativeIntOrQuit(String prompt, String title) {
            String userInputString;
            int userInputInt = -1;

            do {
                userInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt, title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                // Did user hit Cancel or OK with nothing typed?
                if (userInputString == null || userInputString.trim().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No input, so program will terminate now.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                try {
                    userInputInt = Integer.parseInt(userInputString);    // This line might throw an exception.
                    // Ok, if conversion in above line worked, check if input is a positive integer.
                    if (userInputInt < 0)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bad input value. It must be a non-negative integer.",
                                "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bad input value. It must be a non-negative integer.",
                                        "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

            } while (userInputInt < 0);

            return userInputInt;



}

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive written up some code, take it as my solution to your problem.
I would create a hashmap ( or two, one for each player ) and map the game number to the score. You can then use this hashmap to compare scores quite easily

Example ( This is rough code i did it quickly ):

```
public class random {

private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static HashMap<Integer, String> gameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public static void mapScores(){
    System.out.println("How many games have been played?");
    int numOfGames = keyboard.nextInt();

    String score = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfGames; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter the score for game: " + i);
        score = keyboard.nextLine();
        gameMap.put(i, score);
    }


}
```

}

EDIT:

Okay, then i would suggest declaring your integer arrays statically. Makes for easy access. You're saying an array that holds the players scores and the players name, which is why id suggest a hashmap because and array cannot store the name. I'll demonstrate,:

```
public class random {

private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static HashMap<String, int[]> gameMap = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
private static int[] hello = new int[10];

public static void mapScores(int[] array, String name){
     String inputScores = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            inputScores = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(name + " enter your score for game " + i);
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputScores);
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    random.gameMap.put("name", new int[10]);
    random.mapScores(gameMap.get("name"), "name");

    for(int i = 0; i < gameMap.get("name").length; i++){
        System.out.println(gameMap.get("name")[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Obviously i haven't taken the time to correctly create the objects but hopefully you can see the idea despite the bad code. Hope this helps!

Comment: i have to use the void inputScores(int[],String) method to enter a score for each game. An array to hold the player's scores and the player's name

Comment: I see what you mean but it's kind of confusing because youre using different code if you understand im kind of new to this.

Comment: You dont have to use a hashmap if you're unfamiliar, you can just keep the  array static and then use if from their. Hashmaps are great for this kind of question. Try keeping the array static ( the name doesn't need to be, as it's just for user inerface ) at the top of your class and see how that goes.

Comment: I think i figured it out

Comment: I also need help comparing the scores using String compareScores(int[],int[],String,String)

Comment: Not too sure what you're asking but continue! What do you want to return, compute etc